# Batch file for loop including too many files

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, 7-zip

I am using a batch file to compress files in separate archives using 7-zip. The batch file contains this line:

```
FOR %%A IN (*.xls) DO "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" u -mx9 -m0=lzma2:d16m "%%~nA.7z" "%%A"
```

Unfortunately, due to the nature of CMD, it this line compresses both `*.xls` files *and* `*.xlsx` files which i don't intent.

**How do i get it to ignore `*.xlsx`-files?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to test what the file extension is

```dos
for %%A in (*.xls) do if /i "%%~xA"==".xls" (
    "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" u -mx9 -m0=lzma2:d16m "%%~nA.7z" "%%A"
)
```